# When to release MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media, release

I developing an app that has a dozen of buttons and I want to play a beep when a button clicked!

I use following function:

```
public void play_beep()
{
    MediaPlayer mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
    mp.start();
}
```

1. Does MediaPlayer release automatically when `play_beep()` ends?!
2. When I click a button about 20 times then `play_beep()` does not work for a while!

I think I have to release MediaPlayer but I don't know where/When.

Comment: _"but I don't know where/When"_. You can [register](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) an [`OnCompletionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) that will recieve a callback when playback has finished.

Comment: use this `BeepManager` https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/BeepManager.java

Comment: Thank you Michael, I add `OnCompletionListener` and I think problem solved!

Comment: You should use the BeepManager as Abdellah suggests or soundpool if you'll only be playing shorts sounds like beeps

Comment: @Nana Ghartey What is wrong with releasing MediaPlayer in `OnCompletionListener` ?!

Comment: What I mean is MediaPlayer seems heavy for what you trying to achieve. Media player is better for background music, while sound pool is better fort short audio effects (clicks, explosions, sound loops, beems). There's nothing wrong with releasing MediaPlayer in OnCompletionListener.